# Canada GST/HST credit eligibility depends on last year's or current year's income?

Tags: taxes, canada

> The GST/HST credit is a non-taxable amount paid four times a year to individuals and families with low and modest incomes to help offset the goods and services tax/harmonized sales tax (GST/HST) that they pay.

So what tax year do they use to determine if you are of "low and modest income" or not?

- Person A: Made $500K in 2022, Made $20K so far in 2023, is he eligible for payments in 2023?
- Person B: Made $20K in 2022, Made $500K so far in 2023, is he eligible for payments in 2023?